# Phaser scene duplicated when integrating with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, phaser-framework

when embedding this single scene phaser game into React page, the scene was duplicated into two. And every time updating the code, 2 more duplications are added on the page.

Game componenet as below:

```
        import MainScene from './scenes/MainScene.js';
        import Phaser from 'phaser';
        import React, { Component } from 'react'

        class Game extends Component {

        componentDidMount(){
          const config = {
              width: 640,
              height: 1024,
              backgroundColor: '#333333',
              type: Phaser.AUTO,
              parent: 'phaser-game',
              scene: [MainScene]
            };      
          new Phaser.Game(config);
        }
        shouldComponentUpdate() {
          return false;
        }
        render() {
        return <div id="game" />
        }
    
        }

        export default Game;
```

here can see two canvas elements are created
[image]

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem lies in the `config` object, where you are setting the `parent` to `phaser-game`. `parent`is the `id`of the DOM-element, where the canvas should be injected. If an element with that specific `id` can't be found, it is injected into the `body`-tag.

**So the solution** is, to change the `parent` property from `phaser-game` to `game`, as this seems to be the `id` of the element, where you want the game to be displayed.

Just to show the connection, between the `parent` property and the element it refers to.

***Here some code:***

```
 // ...
 componentDidMount(){
     const config = {
         // ... 
         // "id" of the parent DOM Element
         parent: 'game',
         // ...
     };      
     new Phaser.Game(config);
 }
 // ...
 render() {
    // parent DOM Element
    return <div id="game" />
 }
```

**Update:**
the problem *could* be that, `componentDidMount` can run multiple times as mentioned in [this article](https://linguinecode.com/post/understanding-react-componentdidmount), since I don't know your code and I'm no ReactJs expert, you could try to look into this article, how to prevent multiple call of the `componentDidMount` function.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still got these two canvas els in html, the difference is previously they are outside of "root" el and now they are under "game" div. and the strange thing is still every time i update the code, 2 more canvas will be attached. I guess there might be sth wrong with the rendering also?

Comment: @denizc the problem could be also that `componentDidMount` can run multiple times  as mentioned in this article https://linguinecode.com/post/understanding-react-componentdidmount , since I don't know your code and I'm no React expert, you could try to look into this.